# Cannot read property of undefined NodeJs React

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, reactjs

Имеется серверная часть на NodeJs и клиентская на React.
Со стороны сервера использую /api, где передаю полученные данные из mysql:

```
server.use('/api/getCatProduction', (req, res) => {
        res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');

        db.fetchData(models.prodCatQuery('zru'), (error, result) => {
            if(error) 
                console.log(error);
            else {
                res.json(result);
            }
        });
    });
```

В классе страницы получаю их так:

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        data: []
    }
}

componentDidMount() {
    this.getData();
}

getData() {
    fetch('/api/getCatProduction', {
        headers : { 
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'Accept': 'application/json'
        }
    }).then(response => response.json()).then(response => this.setState({data: response}));
}
```

При попытке вывода полученных значений средствами:

```
    const { data } = this.state;

    console.log(data[0].category_name);
    console.log(data[0][category_name]);
    console.log(data[0]["category_name"]);
```

Возникает ошибка

```
productions.js:32 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'category_name' of undefined
```

И никак не могу разобраться в чем проблема... запутался в общем.
Понимаю что решение кроется на самом видном месте, но... видно не судьба найте это самое место)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Изначально ваша `data` это пустой массив `[]`.

Вы делаете асинхронный запрос в `componentDidMount`. При первом рендере ваш `data` будет пустым массивом. И вы хотите взять первый элемент массива и его ключи.

Для того чтобы такого не произошло, вам нужно перед `console.log(data[0].category_name)` сделать проверку: `data.length !== 0`

Comment: Здравствуйте, Илья! Спасибо за ответ. Дело в том, что когда происходит вызов просто `data[0]` или 1, 2... то я получаю определенную ветвь, без переменных которые лежат в ней. Да и по такому же принципу происходит обмен данными на других страницах, там все работает. То есть, как я понимаю, массив уже не может быть пуст. Но как только я пытаюсь забрать определенное значение из ветви, вылезает ошибка. Что это может еще быть?

Comment: Если вы выведите в консоль data, то увидите о чем я говорю, ваш массив будет пустым

Comment: @Иван даю 100% гарантию что он пустой, т.к. в конструкторе вы его определяете как пустой массив, и только после первого рендера делаете асинхронный запрос.

Comment: Да, вы оказались правы. При первом рендере массив и правда инициализируется пустым, по этому и выводится ошибка. Разобрался, спасибо большое)

Comment: @Иван не за что:)